# How can I get XSL 3.0 to work with Pentaho XSL Step

Tags: pentaho, saxon, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, xslt-3.0

I am trying to make use of the XSL 3.0 xml-to-json function in Pentaho but get a compile error when running the transformation.

I believe it’s because Pentaho uses a JAR for XSL 2.0.

I was hoping there is a JAR for XSL 3.0 Pentaho can use that someone can point me to.

Comment: In the Java world XSLT 2 support is usually achieved by using Saxon 9, i.e. by putting a .jar of some Saxon 9 release on the class path. For XSLT 3 you need to move to at least Saxon 9.8, although the current release is 10. So that might work, downloading a Saxon 10 or 9.9 or 9.8 release from saxon.sourceforge.net and putting it on the class path.

Comment: The advice from Pentaho support was to try and replace the saxon-*.9.1.0.8.jar files Pentaho uses with their 9.8 counterparts.  Checking here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/ there doesn't seem to be a later version similar.  The jar Pentaho uses seems to be the last of its iteration (Saxon B) https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/.  Saxon now has HE https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/ with different semblance of JARs. I tried removing the existing JAR, replacing with the HE JAR, then tried adding the HE Jar to existing JAR with no success.

Comment: Ask Pentaho about details or let them answer here, I am afraid I can't tell how they use Saxon 9.1.8 (via JAXP or s9api) and that will probably be the main factor to tell whether simply replacing Saxon 9.1 jars with Saxon 9.8 jars works or can work. You could also add a Saxon tag so that Saxonica or Michael Kay sees your question; he certainly is the most qualified person to ask about Saxon but of course given the age of Saxon 9.1 jumping to 9.8 might require changes in the code using Saxon. So in the end Pentaho should be offering support how to move to XSLT 3, if supported.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen I have made the inquiry with Pentaho as you suggested and await their response.

Comment: Indeed, Saxon 9.1 is over ten years old and there has been a lot of change in the meantime, so I think simply swapping the JAR files is unlikely to work unless Pentaho have confirmed themselves to pure JAXP interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution arrived at-

From the Pentaho Data Integration installation path, take out both /lib/saxon-9.1.0.8.jar and /lib/saxon-dom-9.1.0.8.jar; and replace with only [Saxon-HE-10.5.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/10.5).

After that, I was able to get it to work.

Please note that this function (xml-to-json) only works on specifically formatted XML inputs, and it does not work on arbitrary XML documents:

https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/6299

[https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/fn/xml-to-json.html#:~:text=Converts%20an%20XML%20tree%2C%20whose,Available%20in%20all%20Saxon%20editions](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/fn/xml-to-json.html#:%7E:text=Converts%20an%20XML%20tree%2C%20whose,Available%20in%20all%20Saxon%20editions)

https://www.altova.com/xpath-xquery-reference/fn-xml-to-json